# Right click mouse event bug

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, right-click, mouseleftbuttondown

I tried to fix a bug, for the last hour and I just couldnt.

The bug is:

If you press left click and dont release it, and then press right click (contextual menu appears) and then left click again, the first "drag" action is never released.

Its like, I need to make that my right click says: "hey left click, your job is done, you can go home now".

But I couldnt find a way.

Comment: `Genius needed`, Have you tried the Apple Store?

Comment: Can we see some code? Like the mouse_down and up responder functions.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to listen to stage's mouse move and check `MouseEvent.buttonDown`. If it's false, stop drag:

```
protected function stageMouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (!event.buttonDown)
    {
        myComponent.stopDrag();
    }
}
```

It's important to listen to stage, not to your component, as soon as after context menu hides, the pointer can appear outside component and listeners won't execute.